# How can I find the minimum in Python?

Tags: python

This function finds the maximum and minimum values.

```
n=int(input())
array=list(map(int,input().split))

for i in range(n):
    max=array[0]
    if i>0:
        if max<array[i]:
            max=array[i]
       
for i in range(n):
    min=array[0]
    if i>0:
        if min>array[i]:
            min=array[i]   
            
print(max,end='')
print(     min)
```

The maximum value comes out normally, but the minimum value comes out as the first array value. I can't find what is wrong.

Comment: Please include the sample input, the actual output and the expected output.

Comment: can you please give example and the output you want. the minimum should be correct from the first element. because you loop with in range, where the minum will be always the first element

Comment: You reset both `min` and `max` to `array[0]` on each iteration. Those should be *outside* of the loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The maximum value comes out normally

I think it does only because either your first or last value is the max of the sequence. Because you completely reset both `min` and `max` *on each iteration*. So the entire loop is useless, any iteration but the last has no effect.

The initialisation should be *outside* the loop, not inside of it:

```py
max=array[0]
for i in range(n):
    if i>0:
        if max<array[i]:
            max=array[i]

min=array[0]
for i in range(n):
    if i>0:
        if min>array[i]:
            min=array[i]
```

At which point the check on the index is clearly unnecessary: either eat the unnecessary comparison of `array[0]` to `array[0]` (it's not harmful per-se), or just skip the index when iterating:

```py
max=array[0]
for i in range(1, n):
    if max<array[i]:
        max=array[i]

min=array[0]
for i in range(1, n):
    if min>array[i]:
        min=array[i]
```

In essence you've written a very complicated version of:

```py
if array[0] < array[-1]:
    max = array[-1]
else:
    max = array[0]

if array[0] > array[-1]:
    min = array[-1]
else:
    min = array[0]
```

Now for further improvements, under the assumption that you're trying to learn we'll ignore that [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) and [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) are already built-in functions and thus the entire thing is redundant (although you should *not* name your own variables the same as builtins, as that creates confusion):

- `n` is useless, because it's not checked against `array` and `array` has its own length, `n` can only trigger unnecessary errors if it exceeds `len(array)`, or skip item if it's smaller than `len(array)`. `n` might be useful if e.g. the input was gathered in a loop of validated `input()` call, which is not the case.
- Good error handling would probably check that the length of the array is at least 1, otherwise the script will blow up (although it would also need to check that individual input values are valid before converting to integers so...)
- You can extract min and max in the same loop, no need to loop twice (probably not very important in this case).
- But Python also has good support for iterators, so you should avoid explicit indexing when not necessary, which it is not here.

And my take, still within the realm of trying to learn, would be:

```py
array=list(map(int,input().split))

low = high = array[0]
for candidate in array[1:]:
    if candidate > high:
        high = candidate
    if candidate < low:
        low = candidate

print(f"{low} ... {high}")
```

An other fun alternative is to sort the array and take the first and last elements of the now-sorted array:

```py
array=list(map(int,input().split))

low, *_, high = sorted(array)

print(f"{low} ... {high}")
```

although it has the drawback that it only works on array of length 2+ where the original works on "singleton" arrays.

Comment: `sa=sorted(array); low=sa[0] ; high=sa[-1]` will do the trick also on "singleton" arrays :) .

Answer (score -1):

Use the min and max keyword from python for this.

E.g.

```
my_list = [0, -5, 3, 1, 10]
min_value = min(my_list)
max_value = max(my_list)
print(f'Min value: {min_value}, max value: {max_value}')
```

Comment: While not a bad suggestion, this does not answer the question. Best practices can be part of an answer, but your attempt to answer should address the question as asked.  -1

Comment: The question as stated is "how can I find the minimum in Python". Strictly speaking, the `min` builtin answers the question in full.

Comment: @Masklinn: with *Could you teach me what is wrong??* the question as stated in the title becomes more detailed. Finally turned out that `max`, `min` were not an option, so ... *this does not answer the question* as stated by *Chris* is right. You should generally always read to the very end to know what is a question about.

Comment: The problem is that you reset the min/max variable every iteration. If you move the line `min = array[0]` outside the loop it should work and you also could get rid of the `if i > 0` condition

Comment: @awied1404 : generally worth to know: you improve your own answers by editing them. In the comments to your own answers you respond to questions or hints about the answer or leave in the comments a note that the answer was updated answering the questions or implementing the hints provided in the comments.

Answer (score -1):

Do you just want the min and max of a list of integers a user inputs? Use the build-in functions of python for that:

```
list_of_user_input = []
n_input = int(input("How many variables do you want to enter: "))
for i in range(0, n_input):
    number = int(input(f"Enter variable {i + 1}: "))
  
    list_of_user_input.append(number) 

print(f"The min of your list is {min(list_of_user_input)}")
print(f"The max of your list is {max(list_of_user_input)}")
```

Comment: While not a bad suggestion, this does not answer the question. Best practices can be part of an answer, but your attempt to answer should address the question as asked. -1

Comment: thank you!! but I have to Implementation without built-in function :(